# How to evaluate $\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, gamma-function

How to evaluate $$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}$$, where n is integer > 0?

I know the gamma function formula will give

$$ \frac{(\frac{n-2}{2})!}{(\frac{n-3}{2})!}$$ How to simplify it?

Comment: Is n an integer? You can look at the Gamma function duplication formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: Hint: for $n$ integer use $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$ and $\Gamma(m)=(m-1)\,\Gamma(m-1)$.

Comment: is it going to be (n-1)?

Comment: You can't use the factorial formula for the gamma function when the input is not an integer, which will be the case for one of the numerator or the denominator.  See if you can come up with a general formula for $\Gamma(n+1/2)$ using Raymond's hint.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf: No since you'll have a product of half integers on one side and of integers on the other.

Comment: how can I break it up then to apply the hints you are given?

Comment: $\Gamma(n/2)=(n/2-1)\Gamma(n/2-1)=(n/2-1)(n/2-2)\cdots\Gamma(1/2)$ (or for $n$ even $\cdots \Gamma(1)$).

Comment: still do not see how this can help simply my original question

Comment: $\Gamma((n-1)/2) = ((n-1)/2-1) \Gamma((n-1)/2-1) = ((n-1)/2-1) ((n-1)/2-1) ((n-1)/2-2)$... I do not see these will cancel out with what you wrote, though?

Comment: They won't cancel as I wrote earlier. You'll get a quotient of [double factorials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) like in $(2)$ with a simplification at the end as a [central binomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CentralBinomialCoefficient.html).

Comment: $m=\dfrac n2\iff\lim_{m\to\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma\Big(m\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(m-\tfrac12\Big)} \cdot\dfrac1{\sqrt m}=1$, and $\lim_{m\to\infty}\dfrac{\Gamma\Big(m\Big)}{\Gamma\Big(m+\tfrac12\Big)} \cdot\sqrt m=1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an elaboration of the hint by Raymond Manzoni.

One of $n/2$ and $(n-1)/2$ is an integer, and the other is a half integer, and while there is a nice expression of the gamma function on integers as a factorial, evaluating the gamma function on half integers is more complicated.  However, they can be evaluated using the following facts:

- $\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt{\pi}$
- $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)\Gamma(x-1)$

We then have $\Gamma(n+1/2)=(n-1/2)\Gamma(n-1/2)=(n-1/2)(n-3/2)\Gamma(n-3/2)=\cdots$

Continuing the pattern, we can write

$$\Gamma(n+1/2)=\Gamma(1/2)\left(\frac{1}{2}\frac{3}{2}\cdots \frac{2n-1}{2} \right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}(2n-1)!!}{2^n}.$$

Here, we use the double factorial notation $n!!=n(n-2)(n-4)\cdots (1\text{ or } 2)$  However, we can simplify $(2n-1)!!$ and write it in terms of normal factorials and powers of $2$. Namely, we have 
$$(2n-1)!!=1 \cdot 3 \cdots (2n-1)=\frac{(2n-1)!}{2\cdot 4 \cdots 2(n-1)}=\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}.$$